# Get coordinates of touch in subview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using a UIGestureRecognizer in a scroll view which is inside of my larger view controller. I need to get the coordinates of the touch, which I am not sure how to do without subclassing the scroll view. Any ideas - very much appreciate any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the IBAction of the gesture recognizer, cast sender to whatever type gesture recognizer you're using and say:

```
CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.viewIWantTheCoordinatesIn];
```